# correct word order

Tags: word-order

I'd like to ask if it is correct to say "I'm interested in architecture so the most I'd like to visit places such as Westminster Abbey and the Tower Bridge." I mean if the most goes before the subject and the predicate, is it wrong word order?

Answer (score 2):

The word order in your original sentence is wrong.  A more idiomatic way to phrase it is

> I'm interested in architecture, so **the places I'd most like to visit are**...

This emphasizes the places that you want to visit more than any others - of all places, these are the ones you *most* want to visit.

Another way to phrase it would be

> I'm interested in architecture, so **I'd most like to visit places such as**...

This changes the focus of the sentence a little - of all things, what you would most like is visiting these places.

Comment: But can I say: _... most of all I'd like to visit places such as..._ Is it a very grave mistake to use _the most_ instead of _most of all_?

Comment: Yes, **most of all I'd like to visit places such as** is a good usage.  "The most" just doesn't make sense here.  Idiomatically, "the most I'd like is X" means something like "the maximum that I want is X".